# Stored procedure return value not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Can't seem to get this to work.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlConnection1.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "sp_wth";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter retval = cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string returnvalue = (string)cmd.Parameters["@b"].Value;
lblStatusMessage.Text = returnvalue;
```

Comment: try **string returnvalue = retval.Value**

Comment: I've done similar instances with the user SQL `OUTPUT` key word within stored procs. In the ASP.NET end, `retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec sp_wth", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@b", value));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ParameterDirection. Is it `ReturnValue` or `Output`?

**ParameterDirection.Output** : The parameter is an output parameter.

*Example:*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSP
@b varchar(50) OUTPUT,
...
```

**ParameterDirection.ReturnValue** : The parameter represents a return value from an operation such as a stored procedure, built-in function, or user-defined function.

*Example*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSP
@b varchar(50)
...
return @b
```